# 長時間ブラウザを開いたままの場合だけ起きるJSのバグの再現方法

Tags: javascript

```
$(".foo-select-box").change(function () {
    my_function();
});
```

こういった感じのJSを使っており基本的には問題なく動作してるのですが、ブラウザを丸一日程度開いたままにしておくと正常に動作しないというバグが出てきてしまいました。

対策としては`console.log`を多めに仕込んでおいて何が問題かを特定するぐらいしか思いつかないのですが、長時間ブラウザを開いていた時に起きるバグの再現方法として何かよい方法はありますか？

ちなみに`my_function()`内で`Date`オブジェクトを使った処理はしていません。

Comment: ブラウザの種類とバージョンの情報があると良いと思います。

Comment: MacかWindowsかその他か、OS情報も欲しいですね、またブラウザを1日放置となるとOS側のスクリーンセーバーやら、スリープ設定やらもあるかと思いますが、問題発生時の状態を詳しく記載できますか？他に動作しているソフトや、何か稼動させていたか？など、ふと考えるとCookieとかセッション情報とか時間でなくなるものを使っているかどうかも知りたいですね。`my_function`が大雑把に何をしているか記載できませんか？

Comment: 時刻の変化によるものかどうかを特定する１つの手段として、OSの時刻を変更してみる。

Comment: 「正常に動作しない」はより具体的であると良いと思います。